# adding firmware binary(.bin) in flash image in Modular FIT?

Tags: libraries, binaryfiles, firmware, flashing

I'm encountering difficulties in the process of integrating my firmware binary into the flash image using the Modular FIT tool during the build phase. Despite exploring different approaches, such as modifying the input Manifest file, CodePartition, and CodePartitionMeta file, I haven't been able to incorporate the firmware binary effectively into the image. The challenge lies in ensuring that the firmware binary is correctly included within the flash image so that it can be properly flashed onto the device. This requires precise configuration and accurate referencing within the various files involved in the building process. Despite my efforts, I'm still unable to achieve the desired outcome of having the firmware binary seamlessly integrated into the flash image. Can anyone give me some  assistance or insights on this matter and help me out to build this?

Can someone assist me to build the flash image with the firmware binary in Modular FIT tool?